# ArcGIS '+' operator not working in Spatial Analysis package

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.5

The following python script is working:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = 'C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/ARC_processing'

file_path = 'C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/ARC_processing/MERRA_test_file_0_T.tif'

print(arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial"))

arcpy.Plus_3d(file_path + '/Band_2', file_path + '/Band_3', 'added_bands_4.tif')

print(arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial"))
```

But when I replace the `arcpy.Plus_3d . . .` command with the following:

```
(arcpy.Raster(file_path + '/Band_2') + arcpy.Raster(file_path + '/Band_3')).save('added_bands_4.tif')
```

I get the error message:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I get the same error message when I use other Map Algebra tools that are unique to the Spatial Analyst package (as opposed to also being available from the 3D analyst package, as Plus_3D() is).

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening and how to fix it?

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1.

Comment: Try to use `Plus` tool in arcpy: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/plus.htm

Comment: Are you using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro or with the ArcGIS Desktop 10.x architecture?

Comment: Dont use + to combine paths, instead use `os.path.join`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Comment: You're trying to use Python addition on raster objects? That won't work.

Comment: @Vince, according to http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/spatial-analyst/an-overview-of-the-map-algebra-operators.htm the '+' operator should work when applied to Raster objects.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm using ArcGIS 10.5.1 Desktop

Comment: @ahmadhanb I get the same exit code when I try to use the `Plus` tool.

Comment: The problem is accessing bands in raster calculator/spatial analyst. It's not possible after 9.3 I guess. I am surprised it is possible with 3d analogies.

Comment: I already upvoted your question, nice funding, I'll use 3d plus zero from now. Before it was make raster layer tool.

Answer (score 1):

The comment by FelixIP to my original question turned out to be the issue. It turns out that bands need to be turned into raster layers before those raster layers can be used in Spatial Analyst tools. I used the following command to accomplish this:

```
arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(file_path, 'band_2_layer', '', '', '1')
```

Then the Spatial Analysis commands work fine on the raster layers.

I hope this can help someone else, too!